# Subtext of "fair enough"

Tags: meaning

Say we have an online discussion where I oppose an idea. After reading additional explanation, I realise that both sides have some merit. So while I do not expicitly agree, I want to let the other one know that he has a valid point, and I want to politely withdraw my opposition.

I´d use "fair enough" to express that specific attitude. But when translating it into german, I find additional meanings like "I forgive you" or "whatever, let´s just end this stupid discussion".

Are those so widely adopted usages that fair enough has a negative/offensive meaning?

Comment: See also http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/69115/is-fair-enough-the-same-as-ok

Answer (score 7, accepted):

"Fair enough" is an even-handed acknowledgment that the person on the other side of an argument has made a valid point. It is a concession of sorts, and sometimes may mean that the person saying it wants to drop the discussion, but that is by no means a requirement.

> **Speaker 1**: You said the dinosaurs were killed by an asteroid, but there is mounting evidence that volcanic activity in India may share the blame.
>   **Speaker 2**: Fair enough.

Here "fair enough" means Speaker 2 is merely conceding that what Speaker 1 is saying may be true. It would not express impatience or a desire to discontinue discussion unless Speaker 2 used additional dialogue to make those things clear.

Note: The expression itself is not at all negative and certainly not offensive. In fact, it is often used precisely to avoid giving offense.

Comment: Sounds fair enough to me. What do you think?